# swift parsing xml response odoo

Tags: ios, swift, xml, xcode, xmlmapper

I'm searching a framework to parse xml to a swift class on swift

i have response like that

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <array>
                    <data>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member>
                                    <name>id</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <int>23</int>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                                <member>
                                    <name>name</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <string>20190111_Patient _Test 1_Frank</string>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                                <member>
                                    <name>partner_id</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <boolean>0</boolean>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                    </data>
                </array>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

To parse it i'm trying to use XMLMapper from https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper

parsing is convert from this response to an object

the problem is that response of xml has no name on the nodes how can i parse correctly this thing ? 
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at the built in [XMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) nested mapping with the following model:

```
class MethodResponse: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var members: [Member]?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        members <- map["params.param.value.array.data.value.struct.member"]
    }
}

class Member: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var name: String?
    var value: Value?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        name <- map["name"]
        value <- map["value"]
    }
}

class Value: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var string: String?
    var int: Int?
    var boolean: Int?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        string <- map["string"]
        int <- map["int"]
        boolean <- map["boolean"]
    }
}
```

and map your XML calling `init(XMLString:)` function of `MethodResponse` class like:

```
let methodResponse = MethodResponse(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response i will try to implement your solution, it's seems to be exactly what i want to do

Comment: Thank's for your detailed solution it really helped me a lot